# What am I doing wrong when trying to evaluate this integral using divergence theorem?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**Question:**

[image]

---

**My Attempt:**

**$\color{blue}{\text{My answer to part (b) seems wrong, and I can't figure out why.}}$ Can you guys point out my mistake. Here is what I did:**

The integral is equal to:

$$ \quad \iiint\limits_V \, \nabla \cdot f \ {d} x\,{d} y\,{d}z$$

$$\nabla \cdot f=\frac{df_1}{dx}+\frac{df_2}{dy}+\frac{df_3}{dz}=y+2y+y=4y$$

Therefore, the integral becomes (which can then be easily evaluated):
$$=\int_0^1 \int_0^2 \int_0^4 4y  \ {d} x\,{d} y\,{d}z=32$$

Comment: The integral is more complicated than that because you are dealing with a tetrahedron, not a direct product of intervals

Comment: The bounds of integration are coming from the sides of the tetrahedron.  the upper bounds for the first 2 integrals are not going to be constant.

Comment: Your bounds of the integral describe a rectilinear prism and not a tetrahedron.

Comment: @DougM How do you describe a tetrahedron? Thanks mate :)

Comment: use the first expression of the integral.For each of the four  planes of your tetrahedron, compute the normal vector .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration region is one that lies above the plane $z=0$, below the plane $\frac14 x+\frac12 y+z=1$, and inside the triangular region $x\ge 0$, $y\ge 0$, and $2y+x=4$.  Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_S \vec F\cdot \hat n \,dS&=\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec F\,dV\\\\
&=\int_0^4 \int_0^{2-x/2}\int_0^{1-y/2-x/4}(4y)\,dz\,dy\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^4\int_0^{2-x/2}4y(1-y/2-x/4)\,dy\,dx
\end{align}$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: You're welcome!  It was my pleasure. -Mark